# Find the Number of Solutions in $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + w^3 = 0 \mod 5$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I at first interpreted the question as finding the number of incongruent solutions mod $5$ to the polynomial $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + w^3 = 0$ exactly.  As it turns out, we need to find the number of incongruent solutions mod $5$ to $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + w^3 = 5n = 0 \mod 5$.

I already know that there are 125 incongruent solutions to $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + w^3 = 0$ exactly.  Via induction, the number of solutions to $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i^3 = 0$ has $5^{n-1}$ incongruent solutions.  But I am not entirely understanding what it means to solve $f(x, y, z, w) = 0 \mod 5$.

For example, suppose that $a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + d^3 = 5\text{ mil}$, but $(a, b, c, d)$ may not be congruent to one of the $125$ solutions above.  Thus, unless I know that $(a, b, c, d)$ is congruent to one of the $125$ solutions, or that $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + w^3 = 5 \text{ mil}$ has no solutions, we will have $126$ solutions.  Potentially, all $5^4$ quadruples can solve $x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + w^3 = 0 \mod 5$.  Can someone kindly point me in the right direction?  I think that I am going wildly off-track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: You can choose $x,y,z$ arbitrarily ($5^3$ possibilities) but then the residue class of $w$ modulo $5$ is fixed if you want a sum divisible by $5$. This is because the cubes modulo $5$ cover each residue class once.

Comment: When I view $\mathbb Z_5$ as a field, I know exactly what to do.  I get myself into a knot when I try view it as a polynomial on $\mathbb Z$ and consider each multiple of $5$.  It's up to me to figure out how the result in $\mathbb Z_5$ carries over into $\mathbb Z$ ....